# How to remove additional icons on firefox toolbar

Tags: 11.10, firefox, firefox-extensions

I have a strange problem. I installed **flash and video download** add-on for my firefox browser and I see a bunch of icons in my navigation toolbar. I am not able to remove those bunch of icons by **customize** option. I disabled the add-on and finally uninstalled it completely, but still I have the bunch of icons placed in my navigation bar. I have a screenshot of it as below.
[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestions on how to get it removed is appreciated.

I have **Ubuntu 11.10** and **Firefox 7.0.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reinstall **Flash and video download**;
2. Restart **Firefox**;
3. Select `Tools-->Additional Components` in Firefox menu;
4. Select the extension tab and browse for **Flash and video download**; click Preferences; uncheck show toolbar icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting your default profile for Firefox. Do make sure you backup your bookmarks (Bookmarks/Show All Bookmarks/Import and Backup/Backup...), and make a list of any extensions you want to reinstall. 
Close Firefox, go to your home folder and press CTRL + H to see the hidden files. Then navigate to .mozilla/firefox/XXXXXXXX.default. Make a backup copy of it if you like, then delete it and restart Firefox.

Comment: I deleted the default profile as you said. But I am not able to start firefox after that. It says `Firefox is already running`. But when I go to system monitor, firefox is not listed. I restarted my system and still it reports the same `Firefox is already running`. So what should I do now?

Comment: I restored the deleted folder from Trash and to my surprise, the bunch of icons disappeared. Thanks for your answer. :)